# How to Create Pagination in asp.net mvc without entity framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have two parameters (page_number, paze_size) which I want to use
Any one can help me? I am a new to asp.net MVC.

Comment: Your question could be improved a lot. Please do not type the complete question in the title.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to implement paging in ASP.NET RESTful API using SQL, you could follow this article:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-do-paging-with-asp-net-web-api/

Answer (score 0):

So the code will be as follows. For example, you have a list of products:

```
var products = Products.OrderBy(x => x.Name);

var pagedList = products.Skip(currentPage * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

This will return you the subset of result based on your current page and the number of items required to display.

Comment: In addition to this, also checkout this pagination display library by Jason Watmore: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/10/17/c-pure-pagination-logic-in-c-aspnet

Answer (score 0):

There is an in-build pagination functionality coming with default mvc template. please have a look on this [mvc pagination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)  As well as you can use bootstrap styling for change appearance of the pagination